# How to select from the layer name specific character not whole the name in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder, feature-layer

I am not pro in coding and just recently started using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro. I would like to fill some fields in some attribute tables with the layer name but not the whole name just part of it. How is it possible to say in the field name to get from specific character or just some part of name. For instance, the layer name is "Raster_Conversion_A12_TT" and I just want to fill the field with "A12"

Comment: There are several ways to answer this, but look into the python topic of "string slicing".

Comment: If the term to be extracted is delimited by underscores and always in the same token position (from either end) then research the use of `string.split()` with slicing.